# Can a HDD cause damage to the MoBo?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, external-hard-drive, sata

After a few years since I built my PC it started to freeze and the diagnostic from the Tech Service was a malfunctioning MoBo (SATA related issue). When replacing the MoBo I noticed some damage/corrosion in some of the pins of the SATA connector of the HDD (the power connector was ok) , this issue was not present on other drives. With the new MoBo everything works well and the apparently problematic HDD works fine, but I'm afraid that the drive was the reason that slowly damaged the old MoBo and I don't want it to happen again. The PC has only seen light usage over 4 years and the drive was always connected to only that PC. I want to know if my reasonings might be correct and the HDD can be cause of the MoBo damage and if there's a way to check the health of the drive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrosion and bent pins can cause short circuits so your concern is valid. If you are able to clean up the corrosion and gently straighten the pins (power off of course) and then the board works correctly, it is likely fine.